# How can I keep a file in assets folder using proguard?

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

[image]

I am using proguard to obfuscate my code, so I am keeping my drawables folder out from obfuscation.

I have a .json file in assets folder.
I know how to keep res/drawable but couldn't figure how to keep a file in assets folder?

keep.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@drawable/*"/>
```

Comment: Hey man have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: I am also searching for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys I found a solution.
I moved countries.json from assets folder to raw folder and changed the keep.xml file.

keep.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@drawable/*,@raw/*"/>
```